# How do you play a single NetStream but show different parts of it on different video objects?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, 3d, video-streaming

I have 3D videos encoded with each eye's content side-by-side on each frame. What I want to do is take the left-half and over-lay it on the right-half. (I'll then change with the colors and the overlaying so that someone with blue-cyan 3D glasses can view the video).

I tried to attach a single NetStream to two video objects and offset them, but that only let the stream play on one object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since a [stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_%28computing%29) is by definition a more or less continuous flow of small bits of data, rather than an object of fixed length, you can never access two different positions of a NetStream at the same time. You could try to "jump" between positions from frame to frame, producing a kind of "shutter" effect , but that would probably not perform well.

You can, however, let the video objects share the same NetConnection, and have two NetStream instances load the same movie, or you could just have your content for the left eye and right eye in two separate FLVs playing at the same time. You would have to take care of synchronization, though, and there might by slight inconsistencies.

If you are targeting Flash Player 10.1 or later, you can load both FLVs into memory as a byteArray, and then use [NetStream.appendBytes](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flex_4.0/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29) to play them.  This should take care of the synching problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've since figured out how to accomplish what I want.

pseudo-code:

```
bmd1 = new BitmapData(...);
bmd2 = new BitmapData(...);
bmp1 = new Bitmap(bmd1);
bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmd2);
addChild(bmp1);
addChild(bmp2);

onEnter {
  bmd1.draw(video, ...transformations)
  bmd2.draw(video, ...transformations)
}
```

then organize bmp1 and bmp2 to be where you want the pieces to be, and transform accordingly.